# Adding extracted columns to a table - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my database table Actors, I have two feilds: name and salary.
'name' consists of last and first names separated by a comma and a space.
I am trying to add two more columns: fname and lname, in addition to the existing columns, and I was able to output these two new columns, but I am struggling to add these columns to Actors table.

name / salary -> name / salary / fname / lname

Can someone please help me and let me know how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Here is the sql commands I wrote:

```
select
case when name like '%,%' then
substring(name, charindex(',', name)+2, len(name))
else substring(name, 1, len(name)) end as fname,
case when name like '%,%' then
substring(name, 1, charindex(',', name)-1) end as lname
from Actors;
```

Comment: what database engine? physically add columns (alter table) or separating issue? That is, the question is so vague that you just got an answer on `Alter Table`

Comment: deleted `mysql` tag ... due to charindex()

Comment: it was microsoft sql. Sorry for not specifying more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add new columns to the table, if these are always going to be derived from the existing column.  Instead, add computed columns:

```
alter table Actors add fname as (case when name like '%,%'
                                      then substring(name, charindex(',', name)+2, len(name))
                                      else name
                                 end);

alter table Actors add lname as (case when name like '%,%' then
                                      then left(name, charindex(',', name) - 1)         
                                 end);
```

The values are then computed automatically when you query the table.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just execute these against your database to add the new columns.

```
ALTER TABLE Actors ADD COLUMN fname TEXT
ALTER TABLE Actors ADD COLUMN lname TEXT
```